# Angular-JS app.run is running before Sercives ? How can I change it?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I want to do some config for the menu before I run the application. But the app.run is running after the Service

```
startup.js

    app.run(function ($q, $rootScope,UtilService, MainManuService) {
         //code to modify left menu here
        UtilService.getListMenu().then(function(response){
           // Some config here
            MainManuService.setMenu(response.data);
         })
    })
```

And inside startup I also call a restService `UtilService` to get the dynamic data from database.

index.html:

```
    <script src="scripts/config.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/startup.js"></script>
```

SO is there anyway that I can run the app.run before the service so it can set needed data before the application is start ?
Thank you.

Comment: It is never possible that run method runs after service. See `.run` method runs everytime when your application runs, and then it run your services and controller

Comment: I am creating an example for you to see what happen.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem was cause by the UtilService  required other service so that Service need to run  :(. Then I have not idea to fixed yet.
Anyway Thank you

Comment: Fixed! I defined a `$rootcope=false` for the application manage before the service run.
After I have done setup for the leftmenu I set it back to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.run` method when you have to run your application.
Add all the required services in your `app.js`.
Use `UtilService` in some another file like auth.js,...
Create one method there and use `UtilService` and then call the service in `.run` method.
So your run method will run you util services with the app running.